# Run gcloud auth and gsutil commands in a python script

Tags: subprocess, gcloud, gsutil

I am trying to run three shell commands in a python script using subprocess. I found some code on other threads. I am not receiving any errors but the file is not being uploaded to the bucket. If I open a cmd window and enter all three the file successfully pushes to the bucket. I am using Python 3.6.

```
a = 'gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=C:\key\key.json'
b = 'cd C:\requests'
c = 'gsutil cp *.txt gs://request/upload/'

command = a; b; c

subprocess.run(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Comment: Please consider using the Cloud Storage client library for Python instead of sub-process. As you're discovering, invoke commands in a sub-shell is challenging. See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: Delete command `b`. Use full path names in command `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not receiving any errors because you're not capturing the output stream where errors are printed, `stderr`. Python 3.7+ also requires the `capture_output` argument to be true, but it looks like you're using Python 3.6.

Also, look at this line:

```
command = a; b; c
```

You're storing the string in `a` into the variable `command`. Then, you're just evaluating the next two strings, which basically does nothing; i.e. that line is executing three statements:

```
command = a
b
c
```

I think you probably wanted to concatenate them into one string and pass that as the first arg to `subprocess.run()`:

```
command = '{0}; {1}; {2}'.format(a, b, c)
```

Also, two other things to note:

- If one command is dependent on the previous one succeeding, you should join your commands with `&&` instead of `;`.
- You generally shouldn't rely on `cd`ing into a directory and using relative paths in your shell scripts; try to use absolute paths wherever possible.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes they are dependent on the previous one succeeding. Would that be command = '{0} && {1} && {2}'.format(a, b, c) then? Thanks.

Comment: I deleted the 'b' line and used the full path name of the text file in the c portion. I tried command = '{0} && {1}'.format(a, c)   and   command = '{0}; {1}'.format(a, c)  with no errors but the file is not being uploaded to the bucket.

Comment: If you grab the output of both stdout and stderr via a subprocess pipe, that should provide you with more information.  If you're not getting any output from either stream, your command probably isn't being executed.

Comment: @Andrew Your question shows Windows paths. Windows does not support `&&` which is a Linux shell feature.